# Is there a way to declare a final attribute in an abstract super class and initialize the value in the sub class?

Tags: java, subclass, final, superclass

I'd like to have an abstract super class `Location` with a final attribute `locationNumber`.
But the `locationNumber` should be initialized in the subclass itself like `Market` or `Mosque`. Is there a clean way to do it? I know that it's not going to work like this, it's just to show the problem.

```java
public abstract class Location {
    protected final int locationNumber;
    Collection<Figure> visitors;

    public int getLocationNumber() {
        return locationNumber;
    }
}

public class Market extends Location {
    locationNumber = 5;
}

public class Mosque extends Location {
    locationNumber = 10;
}
```

Comment: Yes. You can initialize the final values inside "constructor"s. If you declare at least a single explicit constructor, then subclasses can (and actually will need to) use that.

Comment: Wow that's rly simple, did't think about that. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a peer working on the same assignment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754039/problem-with-inheritance-in-java-with-getting-the-right-attribute-value ... maybe you two should team up and work together. You know, that student thing of trying to first figure if you can solve problems by yourself ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats how you would do it:

```
public abstract class Location {

    private final int locationNumber;
    Collection<Figure> visitors;

    public Location(int locationNumber) {
       this.locationNumber = locationNumber;
    }

    public int getLocationNumber() {
        return locationNumber;
    }
}

public class Market1 extends Location {

    public Market1() {
       super(5);
    }
}

public class Market2 extends Location {

    public Market2() {
       super(10);
    }
}

Location m1 = new Market1();
Location m2 = new Market2();

System.out.println(m1.getLocationNumber()); // prints 5
System.out.println(m2.getLocationNumber()); // prints 10
```

Answer (score 1):

A final class member variable does not need to be initialized when it is declared. It can be assigned a value in the class constructor or in an initialization block.

```java
public abstract class Location {

    protected final int locationNumber;
    Collection<Figure> visitors;

    protected Location(int locNum) {
        locationNumber = locNum;
    }

    public int getLocationNumber() {
        return locationNumber;
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class Market extends Location {
    public Market() {
        super(5);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could make method `getLocationNumber` abstract and have each subclass return the relevant value. Then you would not need member `locationNumber`.

```java
public abstract class Location {
    Collection<Figure> visitors;

    public abstract int getLocationNumber();
}
```

---

```java
public class Market extends Location {

    public int getLocationNumber() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

But if you still want to keep member `locationNumber` then the following will also work.

```java
public abstract class Location {
    protected final int locationNumber;

    protected Location() {
        locationNumber = getLocationNumber();
    }

    public abstract int getLocationNumber();
}
```

---

```java
public class Market extends Location {

    public int getLocationNumber() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```